# Normalising a column gives back same values?

Tags: r, normalization

I am trying to normalise a column of numerical values to between 0 and 1. I wrote the following R code to try to apply it to a column, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
normalise <- function(x) {
  return (x-min(x)/(max(x)-min(x))) # Creating the function

train$dti_norm <- apply(select(train,dti),MARGIN=2, FUN = normalise)
```

#### It gives me back the same values!

Can someone help me identify why me function doesnt work? Do I have the right input?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there any error message involved? Can you share more sample data if someone wants to run that code and the expected output data?

Comment: You're missing a closing `}` in your function.

Comment: @Jaap i think, your edit made made a big change in the question. Please find my answer.

Comment: Also see `scales::rescale`. Normalizing is often understood to mean that you center the variable and divide by the standard error (like in `scale`).

Comment: hmm ok bro! I will try this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code will help you to standardize your column

```
library(mlr)

trainTask <- normalizeFeatures(trainTask,method = "standardize")
```

This will standardize your data frame and column if you want

Comment: Hey guys, I tried to use multiple columns but the code for the columns argument doesnt work. Able to help me out?

train_norm <- normalizeFeatures(train,method = "range",cols=train['emp_length_num','revol_util'],range=c(0,1))

Answer (score 0):

You were missing some parethesis, no need for `apply`:

```
normalise <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
  } # Creating the function

set.seed(123)
x <- sample(10, 10)
x
#[1]  3  8  4  7  6  1 10  9  2  5


normalise(x)
#[1] 0.2222222 0.7777778 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.5555556 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.8888889 0.1111111 0.4444444


#train$dti_norm <- normalise(train$dti)
```